# Microsoft Excel - getting the right data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have three 3 lists that a user selects from:

1. Rating - AAA,AA,A,BBB
2. Term, 1-3, 3-5, 5-7, 7-10, 10-15, 15+
3. Sector - Fin,Non-Fin, Sec/Col, Sovereign

I'd then like to pick out the relevant cell from the screenshot after the user has selected a value from each list.

I have the drop-downs in D4:D6 on another sheet, and I'd like to select data from the tables in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: it seems my first screenshot has been deleted and only the data has attached.

Comment: Essentially i had 3 option lists. 1) Rating - AAA,AA,A,BBB
                                                  2) Term, 1-3, 3-5, 5-7, 7-10, 10-15, 15+
                                                  3) Sector - Fin,Non-Fin, Sec/Col, Soverign

corresponding to the data, I'd then like to pick out the relevant cell from the screenshot once picking those 3 choices

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Please edit your post to include the details described in your comment. Please also add what you've tried so far.

Comment: @TonyGarcia,,, honestly I'm unable to understand your need,, since the attached screen shot is just filled with data but no clue that from where U are getting data/value and what formula you have applied so far,,, and if this is the output the what modification you need!! Plz [edit] the post & pass complete information to us.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variant of this formula:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("C"&MATCH(K4,C:C,0)),1+MATCH(L4,C5:C8,0),MATCH(M4,D4:I4,0))
```

The first parameter in OFFSET is simply returning the reference to the table header of whichever of the four tables is selected. So, it's in column C and on the row that matches the selected value from "Fin","Non-Fin" etc.

The second parameter is saying "from the table header, go this many rows down" and the third parameter is saying "from the table header, go this many columns across".

Then you have the value you want.

[image]